# Efficient way to get data with same schema from different mysql database (same server)?

Tags: c#, mysql

There are three different MySQL database, db1,db2,and db3.
All of them have same tables and same schema.
If I want to use a c# program to get data in one table from these three sources, which way is more efficient?
1.

```
select * from db1.table1
union
select * from db2.table1
union
select * from db3.table1
```

Then use MySQLDataAdapter to execute this query and save the answer to the result

2.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dbs.length; i++)
{
   // query = "select * from table1"
   // Set MySQLConnection with db[i] connection string
   // use MySQLDataAdapter to get the data from db[i]
   // append the data to result
}
```

Which way is better?

Comment: I would use `UNION ALL`, and not `UNION`

Comment: When all is done on `(same server)`, what is the REAL problem? Why do you want to know what is more efficient? What are your worried about ?

Comment: Suppose `db3.table1` is corrupt (because of some hardware malfunction). Then the first option will give an error quicker than the second option. (Which leaves the question if you really want to consider such things, when taling about efficiency

Comment: Thanks Luuk!  I know that if I create a new connection, it need extra cost to do the connecting job. So I wonder if I use "union" can skip the connecting cost.

Comment: The connection costs should be negligible compared to the time needed to retrieve SELECT * FROM table1`